# SQL Query returns same results running on docker, but not on server

Tags: python, sql, pandas, docker

We recently moved our database to a centralised server for our whole team to use the same data source instead of using dumps from the database and spinning it up in a docker container.

Recently, I noticed that when executing the same SQL-query multiple times on the server returns different results whereas when using the local backup in docker returns the same results when executed multiple times.

The length of the results is the same, but we require a deterministic result of the query which is not given with the server.

This is the code that I used in a jupyter notebook to compare those two queries:

```
sql_query = """
SELECT * FROM reports.consumption
WHERE name LIKE '%%electricity%%'
"""

server_df = pd.read_sql(sql_query,
                        con="<my_credentials_to_server>")
display(server_df.tail(10))

docker_df = pd.read_sql(sql_query,
                        con="<my_credentials_to_local_docker>")
display(docker_df.tail(10))
```

When executing this code multiple times I receive the same tail in the docker version of the database, but not on the server. Why is that the case? Is there some randomness involved?

Comment: Can it be that the centralised database is composed by several replicas which are not in sync?

Comment: Another option: your SQL query does not guarantee to return rows in the same order every time. If it doesn't, your `tail` will be different. Try forcing an order on your query.

Comment: Correct, the centralised server has several DB versions of our dev-DB, but I only access a single one.
And you are also correct that I do not enforce an order, but I don't do that on the docker-db either and there it returns the same result.

Comment: It may not be the order, but the fact that it works as you expect in one deployment does not guarantee anything. You could still get a different order in a different deployment. I'd suggest to add an `ORDER BY` clause. Then you know for sure.

Comment: I tried ordering and this seems to have solved that issue! Thank you! And good to know that the deployment can also play a role in the order.

Comment: There can be several reasons, including: they are running different versions, with different algorithms; the choice of algorithm or parameters could depend on the specific hardware / software / load; the execution plan chooses randomly between two equivalently cost-estimated algorithms.

Comment: Can you put this as an answer? I really like your explanation and would put accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query does not enforce any order. This means that the DB engine is free to choose any. If the same result is returned with a different order from the two deployments, your `tail` will likely be different.

I can imagine a number of reasons why two deployments of the same database may return the same result with a different order, including:

- they may run different versions, which make different algorithmic choices
- the choice of algorithm or parameters may depend on the specific hardware / software / load at hand
- the execution plan may choose randomly between two algorithms that have been estimated to be equally expensive.

I recommend to add an `ORDER BY` clause to enforce a specific order on all deployments, or to sort your dataframe in Python.